# firebase 3 way data binding via inner join

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-binding

Am I able to setup 3 way data binding like this?

```
                findAllItems: function() {
                var user = User.getCurrent();

                if (angular.isObject(user)) {

                    var indexRef = fbRefs.users().child(user.uid).child('items');
                    var join = Firebase.util.intersection(
                        indexRef,
                        fbRefs.items()
                    );

                    return $firebase(join);
                }
            },
```

Controller:

```
Palace.findAllItems().$bind($scope, 'items');
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input ng-model="item.something" />
```

This display everything nicely but when I edit something in view it throws an security error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /items failed: permission_denied
```

And my security rule look like:

```
    "items": {   
      "$itemId": {
        ".write": true
```

Anyone have a clue what's wrong please?

Comment: When you save an item in Firebase.util, it writes to the index and to the data. It's probably being denied on the index portion of the write?

Comment: The problem is that this is working:  

"items": {   ".write": true